# Is "equals to," as in "one plus one equals to two," ungrammatical?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, phrase-usage, mathematics, style-manuals

I study mathematics alongside many Chinese students. They will often use the phrase "equals to," as in "one plus one equals to two." Is this usage incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Because you are new here and the question is not entirely trivial, I have answered your question but I recommend that you show some evidence of your own research when you ask questions. We like to help those who have first tried to help themselves. Otherwise you may find your questions closed.

Comment: This wrongly conflates 'Two plus two equals four' and 'Two plus two is equal to four'. In symbols, 2 + 2 = 4 The equals sign is equivalent to 'equals' (no matter whether the LHS, the preceding, is a single number or twenty) _or_ 'is equal to' (no matter whether the LHS, the preceding, is a single number or twenty). It can be read out either way (the shorter way is, as you might expect, more usual).

Comment: Now, you can correct them.

Answer (score 1):

To use *equal* as a verb, consider two examples of the many dictionary definitions:

> equal (verb) = to have the same value, size, etc as something else, often shown using a symbol (=):
>
> "Two plus two equals four."
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/equal_2)

> equal: transitive verb
>
> to be equal to
> especially : to be identical in value to
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equal)

Hence we say *"2+2 equals 4"* (The Cambridge example)

This is equivalent to saying *"2+2 is identical in value to 4"* (the Merriam Webster example)

To say *"2+2 equals to 4"* fits neither of these usages. It is therefore incorrect, or at least it uses *"to"* unnecessarily.

Comment: Crucial to resolving the OP's problem is that the phrase *two plus two* **as a whole** should be thought of as the subject here, and treated as being in the singular.